# How to export Google Analytics Data to Google Sheets or Excel files?

Tags: excel, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

Found [this method of writing a custom Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script). Is there no simpler way to export each table by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export any table by going to the Export menu and selecting your file preference from that menu.

[image]

Comment: Additionally you can use an unsampling and clickstream extractor like http://www.scitylana.com and do the analysis in another tool, like Excel/Tableau or the like